# How to calculate distances from coordinates stored in lists

Tags: list, coordinates, distance

So far I managed to calculate the distances between an Point P(x,y) and a multitude of points stored in a list l = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), ...) Here is the code :

```
import math
import pprint
```

```
l = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]
p = (3,3)
```

```
dists = [math.sqrt((p[0]-l0)**2 + (p[1]-l1)**2) for l0, l1 in l]
pprint.pprint(dists)
```

Output :

```
[2.23606797749979, 1.0, 2.23606797749979]
```

Now I want to calculate the distances from multitude points in a new list to the points in the list l.
I haven't found a solution yet, so does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: Please provide the code you have written so far, and what bit you cant get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from math import sqrt

def distance(p1, p2):
    return sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2)

lst1 = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]
lst2 = [(6,7), (8,9), (10,11)]

for p1 in lst1:
    for p2 in lst2:
        d = distance(p1, p2)
        print(f'Distance between {p1} and {p2}: {d}')
```

Output:

```
Distance between (1, 2) and (6, 7): 7.0710678118654755
Distance between (1, 2) and (8, 9): 9.899494936611665
Distance between (1, 2) and (10, 11): 12.727922061357855
Distance between (2, 3) and (6, 7): 5.656854249492381
Distance between (2, 3) and (8, 9): 8.48528137423857
Distance between (2, 3) and (10, 11): 11.313708498984761
Distance between (4, 5) and (6, 7): 2.8284271247461903
Distance between (4, 5) and (8, 9): 5.656854249492381
Distance between (4, 5) and (10, 11): 8.48528137423857
```